# C# - Search a file from hard drive

Tags: c#

I want to search a file which resides in specific folder,when i click a button  it will be open in windows explorer..

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        DirectoryInfo hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch = new DirectoryInfo("H:\\studio\\");
        FileInfo[] filesInDir = hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch.GetFiles("*" + txt_mobile .Text  + "*.*");

        foreach (FileInfo foundFile in filesInDir)
        {
            string fullName = foundFile.FullName;


            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fullName  , FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {

            }

        }

    }
```

I cant open the file containing folder,which is specified in "fullName" string.

Comment: Why don't you look at the documentation?

Comment: Could you please remove the caps from the head? and include the code that you are using now?

Comment: I've edited your question but please remember, when you post questions to stack overflow that you have to use proper spelling & grammar. Don't use slang words and try to be specific and `to-the-point`. Q&A sites are no place for slang, you are trying to get help from people not confuse them even more . Now with that being said, Good luck and Welcome to Stack Overflow 

Comment: @Mango you've added more thank you text to this overly broad post that it started from. Please don't do that in this/future edits (if you need to discuss - ask question on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) like http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'll take that into consideration next time, thanks again for the link and the info.

Comment: *I cant open the file containing folder*. Why not? What's stopping you? In what **specific way** can you not open the folder? What happens when you try? Do you get an error? If so, what specific error do you get? You need to be **specific** about the problem you're having if you want us to help you. Make it **very clear** what problem you've encountered (including the **exact** error message you're getting, if any). If you want us to help, provide the details we need in order to do so.

Comment: By clicking the button3 nothing happens.Not even show the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick for you

[FileDialog.InitialDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) would be going to help you. Since `initial directory` displays by the file dialog box. And FileDialog.FileName can initialize to a preset file name.

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
//Take out only the directory path instead of full path.
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = TextBoxPath.Text; 
//Take out only the file name instead of full path.
openFileDialog1.FileName = TextBoxPath.Text;
```

Hope this helps