# Change Path of OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#

At the moment I am using this here in my WPF App which works as it should.

```
private void buttonPresentations_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialogPresentations.ShowDialog();
        }
```

It remembers the last path I was in but I want to change it to a set path now.
I have 3 Radiobuttons and each Radiobutton should lead to a different path so I thought about doing it with a variable I give to the openFileDialog but I am not sure on how to go with that. Has anyone done this and can give me a lead on it ?

Comment: Set the InitialDirectory property to your desidered initial path

Comment: Hope [Locating file on hard drive](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38580437/3796048) might help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set [IntitialDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) to the folder you want in code where you show the dialog.

```
private void buttonPresentations_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFileDialogPresentations.IntitialDirectory = youFolderPath;
    openFileDialogPresentations.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks Steve got me on the right path there :) I just put that in front of my ShowDialog and works fine now!

Comment: @BlackPanic then consider marking this or the answer that helped you the most as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The standard file dialogs have an [`InitialDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) property that determines in which folder the dialog opens.

```
private void buttonPresentations_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFileDialogPresentations.InitialDirectory = @"X:\Data\Presentations";
    openFileDialogPresentations.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using InitialDirectory property. You can set three different paths for radio buttons

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            dialog.InitialDirectory=@"D:\MyDir";
            dialog.ShowDialog();
        }
```